# Doing pairwise distance computation with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, distance

I'm trying to impelement this article:
http://ronan.collobert.com/pub/matos/2008_deep_icml.pdf
Specfically the equation (3) from section 2.

Shortly I want to do a pairwise distance computation for the features of each mini-batch and insert this loss to the general network loss.
I have only the Tesnor of the batch (16 samples), the labels tensor of the batch and the batch feature Tensor.

After looking for quite a while I still couldn't figure out the following:

1) How do I divide the batch for Positive (i.e. same label) and negative pairs. Since Tensor are not iterateble I can't figure out how to get which sample have which label and then divide my vector, or get which indices of the tensor belong to each class.

2) How can I do pairwise distance calculation for some of the indices in the batch tensor?

3) I also need to define a new distance function for negative examples

Overall, I need to get which indices belong to which class, do a positive pair-wise distace calculation for all positive pairs. And do another calculation for all negative pairs. Then sum it all up and add it to the network loss.

Any help (to one of more of the 3 issues) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If your distance metric is euclidian, you can use tf.gather to create a matrix just out of vectors of interest, and then there's an efficient way to compute all pairwise distances as in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37040451/419116)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1)
You should do the pair sampling **before** feeding the data into a session. Label every pair a boolean label, say y = 1 for matched-pair, 0 otherwise.

2) 3) Just calculate both pos/neg terms for every pair, and let the 0-1 label **y** to choose which to add to the loss.

---

First create placeholders, y_ is for boolean labels.

```
dim = 64
x1_ = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=(None, dim))
x2_ = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=(None, dim))
y_ = tf.placeholder('uint8', shape=[None])   # uint8 for boolean
```

Then the loss tensor can be created by the function.

```
def loss(x1, x2, y):
    # Euclidean distance between x1,x2
    l2diff = tf.sqrt( tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.sub(x1, x2)),
                                    reduction_indices=1))

    # you can try margin parameters
    margin = tf.constant(1.)     

    labels = tf.to_float(y)

    match_loss = tf.square(l2diff, 'match_term')
    mismatch_loss = tf.maximum(0., tf.sub(margin, tf.square(l2diff)), 'mismatch_term')

    # if label is 1, only match_loss will count, otherwise mismatch_loss
    loss = tf.add(tf.mul(labels, match_loss), \
                  tf.mul((1 - labels), mismatch_loss), 'loss_add')

    loss_mean = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
    return loss_mean

loss_ = loss(x1_, x2_, y_)
```

Then feed your data (random generated for example):

```
batchsize = 4
x1 = np.random.rand(batchsize, dim)
x2 = np.random.rand(batchsize, dim)
y = np.array([0,1,1,0])

l = sess.run(loss_, feed_dict={x1_:x1, x2_:x2, y_:y})
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! BTW it is better to use reLu instead of max. But the rest of code I used as is. Thanks!

Comment: what should be the value of `margin`?

Comment: @Mithun it is a parameter you can tune. I'm not sure what's the best practice now, but the default in Caffe is 1.0 (http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/contrastiveloss.html)

Answer (score 7):

#### Short answer

I think the simplest way to do that is to **sample the pairs offline** (i.e. outside of the TensorFlow graph).
You create `tf.placeholder` for a batch of pairs along with their labels (positive or negative, i.e. same class or different class), and then you can compute in TensorFlow the corresponding loss.

---

#### With the code

1. You sample the pairs offline. You sample `batch_size` pairs of inputs, and output the `batch_size` left elements of the pairs of shape `[batch_size, input_size]`. You also output the labels of the pairs (either positive of negative) of shape `[batch_size,]`

```py
pairs_left = np.zeros((batch_size, input_size))
pairs_right = np.zeros((batch_size, input_size))
labels = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))  # ex: [[0.], [1.], [1.], [0.]] for batch_size=4
```

2. Then you create Tensorflow placeholders corresponding to these inputs. In your code, you will feed the previous inputs to these placeholders in the `feed_dict` argument of `sess.run()`

```py
pairs_left_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, input_size])
pairs_right_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, input_size])
labels_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 1])
```

3. Now we can perform a feedforward on the inputs (let's say your model is a linear model).

```py
W = ...   # shape [input_size, feature_size]
output_left = tf.matmul(pairs_left_node, W)  # shape [batch_size, feature_size]
output_right = tf.matmul(pairs_right_node, W)  # shape [batch_size, feature_size]
```

4. Finally we can compute the pairwise loss.
   [image: Loss]

```py
l2_loss_pairs = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(output_left - output_right), 1)
positive_loss = l2_loss_pairs
negative_loss = tf.nn.relu(margin - l2_loss_pairs)
final_loss = tf.mul(labels_node, positive_loss) + tf.mul(1. - labels_node, negative_loss)
```

---

And that's it ! You can now optimize on this loss, with a good offline sampling.